# ploting time series with day time in horizontal axis

Tags: r, time-series

Hi there I have some working code that selects data from a single station and plots it as a time series.in this data is a date time of the format:

28     11AC068 2018-08-30T02:15:00-06:00
29     11AC068 2018-08-30T02:20:00-06:00

```
file = "http://dd.weather.gc.ca/hydrometric/csv/SK/hourly/SK_hourly_hydrometric.csv"
skdat <- read.csv(file, head=T, sep=",", dec=".")
skdate <- skdat 
colnames(skdat) <- c("ID", "Date", "Water.Level", "Grade.1", "Symbol.1", 
                     "QA/QC-1", "Discharge/Debit", "Grade.2", "Symbol.2", 
                     "QA/QC-2")

#There are 151 Factors of ID
str(skdat$ID)
skdat$Date <- as.Date(skdat$Date, "%h/%m")
#"05AH050","05EF001"#,..: 151 151 151 151 151 151 151 151 151 151 ...
plot.ts(subset(skdat,  skdat$ID=='05EF001')$Water.Level, main="Plot TS of ID = 05EF001")
axis.Date(1, at=seq(min(skdat$Date), max(skdat$Date), by="hour"), format="%h-%m")
```

in the subset the date time is filtered out is there any way to keep that column in the data and use it to plot the horizontal axis just as hour min?

Comment: can you please use `dput()` and give a small subset of your data

Comment: Hi Suhas I get the data from that online source there

Answer (score 2):

You could try something like this.

```
library(tidyverse)

file = "http://dd.weather.gc.ca/hydrometric/csv/SK/hourly/SK_hourly_hydrometric.csv"
skdat <- read.csv(file, head=T, sep=",", dec=".", stringsAsFactors = F)
colnames(skdat) <- c("ID", "Date", "Water.Level", "Grade.1", "Symbol.1", 
                     "QA/QC-1", "Discharge/Debit", "Grade.2", "Symbol.2", 
                     "QA/QC-2")

skdat %>% filter(ID=='05EF001') %>% 
  mutate(Date = gsub("-06:00$", "", Date) %>% lubridate::parse_date_time(., orders = "ymd HMS")) %>%
  ggplot(aes(Date, Water.Level))+
  geom_line()+
  scale_x_datetime(breaks = "4 hours", date_labels = "%H:%M")
```

[image]

Created on 2018-09-01 by the [reprex
package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Comment: WHOA! cool that solves my conversion to ggplot too! thanks AndS!

Comment: hmmm 1 quick question i get this when i run it  Error: could not find function "%>%"

Comment: No problem, that function should be loaded automatically when you use the tidyverse package. It comes from the magrittr package, so you could also try loading that package directly if you’re having trouble

Comment: I cant seem to gett around this error , I tried using magrittr and reprex I thin it is a version thing + scale_x_datetime(breaks = "4 hours", date_labels = "%H:%M")
Error in strsplit(unitspec, " ") : non-character argument

Comment: I am using version.string R version 3.3.3 (2017-03-06)

Comment: It could be a version issue, but I can’t say for sure. I’m using 3.5

Comment: OK ill try using a newer version and see if it goes away

Comment: still having probels with %>%"  so in that line skdat %>% filter(ID=='05EF001') %>%  what exactly is going on?

Comment: `skdat` is the dataframe, `%>%` is the pipe operator from the magrittr package (loaded automatically with any of the tidyverse packages), and filter is from the dplyr package. You can read the pipe as the word "then". So what is going on is: first start with the dataframe, THEN filter the data to only have ID 05EF001, THEN change the date variable to a date format, THEN make the plot.